# DataSet Designer: add exact duplicate table?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I am creating a DataSet (call it Foo) in the DataSet Designer.

It has a DataTable named Bar. It doesn't have an underlying database table; stuff gets filled in in an application-specific manner. So far so good.

The code generator creates classes Foo, Bar, and BarRow. And within the Foo class there's a private member of type Bar called tableBar, also generated.

With me so far?

I want to add another DataTable that's *exactly like* tableBar, but will contain semantically different information. It won't do to reuse tableBar, because some parts of my application will need both sets of data. But I want the new table to be of class Bar also, because several methods in my application code need to be able to interpret both "old" and "new" tables.

In other words, I'm trying to get the DataSet Designer to do this:

```
public class Foo: DataSet
{
    public class Bar
    {
        // ... stuff ...
    }
    private Bar tableBar;
    private Bar tableBaz; // <--- this is the new table! Note no separate class Baz.
}
```

So I'm wondering how to use the DataSet Designer, or how to modify the underlying .XSD file, to support two DataTable objects, within the DataSet, that are of the same DataTable inherited class.

Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: Too abstract, what means semantically different?

Comment: Two DataTables. Exact same structure. Different stuff in them. In the specific application, one is "current" data and the other is "historic" data which for business purposes we maintain and query separately, but the structure of the data is the same in both tables.

Comment: So in other words you're just asking if one `DataSet` can contain multiple `DataTables` of the same type. Of course. But you wouldn't define it as separate table but initialize it, load it and then add it to the `DataSet` instance manually. I think you're mixing classes and instances here.

Comment: That would work! The downside is that the first instance would be hardcoded into the definition of the DataSet and could be referenced as fooInstance.tableBar whereas the second would need a clunkier reference like (Bar) fooInstance.Tables["BAZ"], which weakens the strong typing just a little.

Is there a clean way to do this within the DataSet Designer?

Comment: The normal way with a strongly typed DataSet would be to add two tables in the designer which query the same table in sql. Why was that a problem?

Comment: My first approach don't require to "hardcode" an instance. You create two instances of the _same_ `DataTable` in code. `Bar tableBar = new Foo.Bar();Bar tableBaz = new Foo.Bar();`. Then you use both however you like.

Comment: Q. Why was that a problem? A. Because lots of app code wanted to access both bar and baz at different times. They needed to be of compatible types.